# Copiar registros de uma tabela para outra através de select

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou copiando os registros de uma tabela para outra, em bancos diferentes, porém uma coluna na tabela nova não pode ser nula e os dados vindos da tabela antiga são nulos.
Existe uma forma de colocar algum condicional para que "transforme" os campos nulos em algo que eu queira ?

Abaixo a query que estou utilizando

```
insert into banco_novo.cliente (codcliente, nome, cpf, rg, sexo, data_nascimento, endereco, bairro, cidade, estado, cep) (select codcliente, nome, cpf, rg, sexo, data_nascimento, endereco, bairro, cidade, estado, cep from banco_antigo.cliente)
```

Comment: Você pode usar um [Insert Select](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) e no `select` definir a condição para os campos que serão nulos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existe a função [IF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) com ela você pode "transformar" os valores nulos em algum outro valor no seu `insert... select`, veja este exemplo:

```
insert into table2(nome)
select if (nome is null,'padrao para nulo', nome)
from table1;
```

Os valores que viram como nulos do campo `nome` passaram a conter o valor `'padrao para nulo'`.

Veja o código funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ceb60/1).

Comment: Resolvi de forma parecida: `insert into banco_novo.cliente (codcliente, nome, cpf, rg, sexo, data_nascimento, endereco, bairro, cidade, estado, cep) (select codcliente, nome, cpf, rg, IFNULL(sexo, 'I'), IFNULL(data_nascimento, '2000-01-01'), endereco, bairro, cidade, IFNULL(estado, '0'), cep from banco_antigo.cliente)`